# Таймеры в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне в одном классе нужно реализовать два таймера: первый бесконечно (или пока сцена с игрой не будет закрыто) должен каждые m секунд выполнять действие (1), второй каждые n секунд действие (2). Нужно учитывать то, что есть в игре пауза, и при её вызове нужно таймеры на паузу ставить (я бы мог сделать через корутины, но не знаю как их ставить на паузу). Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый банальный способ это иметь флаг, который устанавливается `true/false` когда игра активна/на паузе. В зависимости от этого флага уже танцевать в корутине.

Как пример:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TimerTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isGameStopped = false;
    private int timer = 0;

    IEnumerator WaitAndPrint() {        
        while(true) {       
            if (!isGameStopped) {
                Debug.Log("TimerCount: " + (timer++));
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);             
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void Start() {  
        StartCoroutine(WaitAndPrint());     
    }
}
```

Естественно `isGameStopped` скорее всего будет не в самом этом классе. Но это уже вам решать где его делать и в какой момент и каким способом его менять.

Смысл тут в том, что если флаг `false`, то будет простой банальный выход из корутины `yield return null;`. В ином же случае будет заход в `if (!isGameStopped)` и срабатывание счетчика.

---

Еще вариант - стартовать и останавливать корутину при возникновении какого-либо события (паузы)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TimerTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isGameStopped = false;
    private int timer = 0;
    private IEnumerator coroutine;

    IEnumerator WaitAndPrint() {        
        while(true) {                       
            Debug.Log("TimerCount: " + (timer++));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);                             
        }
    }


    void Start() {      
        coroutine = WaitAndPrint();
    }


    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
             StartCoroutine(coroutine);

         if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")){
            StopCoroutine(coroutine);
        }

    }
}
```

В данном случае корутина запускается нажатием левой клавиши мыши, а останавливается нажатием на пробел. Но привязать это поведение к паузе, думаю сможете сами.

---

Для `float`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TimerTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isGameStopped = false;
    private float timer = 0.0f;
    private float timeDelta = 0.0f;
    private IEnumerator coroutine;

    IEnumerator WaitAndPrint() {        
        while(true) {                               
            timer = Time.time - timeDelta;          
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void Start() {          
        coroutine = WaitAndPrint();
        StartCoroutine(coroutine);
    }


    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            timeDelta = Time.time - timer;
            StartCoroutine(coroutine);           
        }

         if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")){
            StopCoroutine(coroutine);            
            timeDelta = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

`Time.time` - время с начала игры.
`timeDelta` - вычисляется когда запускается корутина, и обнуляется, когда останавливается.

---

Вообще, зависит от того, каким образом происходит пауза в игре.

Например, в некоторых случаях программисты делают паузу делая значение глобального времени **[Time.timeScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html)** равным нулю. Тогда всё останавливается.  В том числе и время `Time.time`. Если `Time.timeScale` равно единице, то это полная игровая скорость.

Соответственно, если пауза делается именно через `timeScale`, то, в принципе, достаточно отслеживать `Time.time`, который будет показывать нужное время. А если пауза делается другими способами, но `Time.time` неизменно течет, то тогда  делать примерно как описано в коде выше.

Comment: Сделал так, как у вас во втором примере. Таймер таким образом не ставится на паузу, а сбрасывается. То есть до действия определенного остается несколько секунд, игрок нажимает на паузу, потом возобновляет и отсчёт идет по новому, а не с предыдущего значения времени.

Comment: @NikitaMedvedev не может быть такого. Потому что значение сохраняется в переменную `private int timer` который не может идти заново, если только вы где-то её сами не обнуляете. или вы имеете в виду точность до миллисекунд?

Comment: все, понял, я буду считать timer. Когда дойдет до нужного значения, выполнить нужное действие. Я думал, можно как нибудь без подсчета количества выполнения функции выполнять

Comment: @NikitaMedvedev добавил еще пару описаний в ответ. Если вы используете для паузы `Time.timeScale` тогда все таймеры скорее всего сведутся к отслеживанию `Time.time` без всяких корутин